# Checking whether or not 2 types are comparable

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

I have the following code to determine whether or not 2 types are comparable.

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct is_comparable
    : std::false_type
{};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_comparable<T, U, std::void_t<decltype((std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>()))>>
    : std::true_type
{};
```

Is this an acceptable way of archieving what I am trying to do? Can you see any problems with this design?

**EDIT**

Keeping cdhowie's comment and Henri Menki's answer in mind, this is how the code looks now.

```
namespace meta
{
    template<typename T, typename U, typename = std::void_t<>>
    struct has_equal_to_operator
        : std::false_type
    {};

    template<typename R, typename T, typename U, typename = std::void_t<>>
    struct has_equal_to_operator_r
        : std::false_type
    {};

    template<typename T, typename U, typename = std::void_t<>>
    struct has_nothrow_equal_to_operator
        : std::false_type
    {};

    template<typename R, typename T, typename U, typename = std::void_t<>>
    struct has_nothrow_equal_to_operator_r
        : std::false_type
    {};

    template<typename T, typename U>
    struct has_equal_to_operator<T, U, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>())>>
        : std::true_type
    {};

    template<typename R, typename T, typename U>
    struct has_equal_to_operator_r<R, T, U, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>())>>
        : std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>()), R>
    {};

    template<typename T, typename U>
    struct has_nothrow_equal_to_operator<T, U, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>())>>
        : std::bool_constant<noexcept(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>())>
    {};

    template<typename R, typename T, typename U>
    struct has_nothrow_equal_to_operator_r<R, T, U, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>())>>
        : std::bool_constant<(noexcept(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>()) && std::is_convertible_v<decltype(std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>()), R>)>
    {};

    template<typename T, typename U>
    inline constexpr auto has_equal_to_operator_v = has_equal_to_operator<T, U>::value;

    template<typename R, typename T, typename U>
    inline constexpr auto has_equal_to_operator_r_v = has_equal_to_operator_r<R, T, U>::value;

    template<typename T, typename U>
    inline constexpr auto has_nothrow_equal_to_operator_v = has_nothrow_equal_to_operator<T, U>::value;

    template<typename R, typename T, typename U>
    inline constexpr auto has_nothrow_equal_to_operator_r_v = has_nothrow_equal_to_operator_r<R, T, U>::value;
}
```

Comment: I'd clarify `is_equality_comparable` because there are other kinds of comparisons (inequality, relational...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with `void_t` like in the question.  Additionally I would check if the comparison produces the correct type (`bool` in this case).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template < typename T, typename U >
using equality_comparison_t = decltype(std::declval<T&>() == std::declval<U&>());

template < typename T, typename U, typename = std::void_t<> >
struct is_equality_comparable
  : std::false_type
{};

template < typename T, typename U >
struct is_equality_comparable < T, U, std::void_t< equality_comparison_t<T,U> > >
  : std::is_same< equality_comparison_t<T,U>, bool >
{};

struct X {};

struct Y { int operator==(Y const&) { return 1; } };

int main()
{
  static_assert(false == is_equality_comparable<X, X>(), "!");
  static_assert( true == is_equality_comparable<std::string, std::string>(), "!!");
  static_assert(false == is_equality_comparable<int, std::string>(), "!!!");
  static_assert( true == is_equality_comparable<int, int>(), "!!!!");
  static_assert(false == is_equality_comparable<Y, Y>(), "!!!!!");
}
```

Comment: is there a specific reason for changing `std::declval<T>()` to `std::declval<T&>()` ?

Comment: @Yamahari No, actually not.  I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: Nowadays with C++20, you might want to use the [`std::equality_comparable` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/equality_comparable)

Answer (score 0):

You're not far but you don't need C++17: it's enough C++11

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename U, typename = void>
struct is_comparable : std::false_type
 {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_comparable<T, U,
   decltype((std::declval<T>() == std::declval<U>()), void())>
    : std::true_type
 {};

struct X
 { };

int main()
 {
   static_assert(false == is_comparable<X, X>(), "!");
   static_assert( true == is_comparable<std::string, std::string>(), "!!");
   static_assert(false == is_comparable<int, std::string>(), "!!!");
   static_assert( true == is_comparable<int, int>(), "!!!!");
 }
```

Comment: I am using C++17 in the rest of my code, so might aswell use it here :) still thanks!

Comment: Why would you write `true == f()` instead of just... `f()`

Comment: @Barry - an aestethical reason: I don't like the "!" operator (it's too small: I don't' see it!) so, when I write code when I check true and false value, I explicit it. I know... it's superflous. But I find it more clear and simmetric.